# deleting a row where a particular column is empty

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called `contacts` and a column called `name`. I'm trying to delete rows where the name field is empty.

I make the following call

```
delete from contacts where name=''
```

This doesn't work as expected; the row is not being deleted.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try `where name is null`.

Comment: perhaps `where (name='' or name is null)`

Answer (score 1):

Start by examining `select id, name, len(name) from contacts order by name` so you can find out whether there are spaces or other gobbledygook that look like an empty name but have non-zero length.